# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'" modernizr

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I have created new asp.net mvc 5 project in visual studio 2015 professional
And I have added meta tag in my layout for Content Security Policy as -

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
  content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
  connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';" />
```

Now when I run my application I get following error in chrome browser console -

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CwE3Bg0VYQOIdNAkbB/Btdkhul49qZuwgNCMPgNY5zw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
>   modernizr-2.6.2.js:157

There are 6 errors for modernizr-2.6.2.js:157 and one is related to script, i.e. refused to load the script localhost

I don’t think I have any inline style in my project and then why CSP refused to apply error ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766817/refused-to-apply-inline-style-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently modernizr either injects a `style` element with some CSS properties, or else injects some `style` attributes; you can deal with it by changing your CSP policy this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
  content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
  connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' 'sha256-CwE3Bg0VYQOIdNAkbB/Btdkhul49qZuwgNCMPgNY5zw=';" />
```

Comment: thanks @sideshowbarker , that's what i am trying to do and yes it solves my issue, but the problem is i have to do this for all of the errors for my application and this is too much almost 50 errors and i have to copy each hash and add it to respective directive values, any shortcut will be very helpful.

Comment: If modernizr is injecting all that inline stuff than it seems like your choices are to either (a) add all those hashes, (b) use 'unsafe-inline' (but which basically defeats the whole purpose of CSP…), or (c) don’t use modernizr