# Getting "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy" error

Tags: .net-core

I am getting the below error while running the application

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/ 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Below is the code currently I am using

```
const string modernizrHash1 = "sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=";
            const string modernizrHash2 = "sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs=";
            app.UseCsp(options => options
                .DefaultSources(s => s.Self())
                .ScriptSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/"))
                .StyleSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/", modernizrHash1, modernizrHash2))
                .FontSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/"))
                .ImageSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("data:"))
            );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766817/refused-to-apply-inline-style-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security

Answer (score 4):

The hash `4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ=` is for the CSS `word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;`, the inline style Chrome automatically applies when you are not serving a HTML document;

Example server response:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 11:33:49 GMT

some text
```

DOM in Chrome

```html
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">some text</pre></body></html>
```

Console error

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"
> . Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.```

Adding the hash to `default-src` or `style-src` won't help because it is an "inline style" and "hashes do not apply to style attributes".

The best fix is to make sure you serve a proper HTML document with your CSP header, so browsers don't decorate it with their own styling.

Comment: Thank you. Quote: “Adding the hash to default-src or style-src won't help because it is an "inline style" ”  Please share also a reference link to documentation. 
Now it fires in console:  “Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.”   So the isecure bypass  'unsafe-hashes'  which is only solution for testing environment :) .

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the inline styles (which can be hashed to `sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ=`) aren't allowed, as per your Content Security Policy and the error that is returned.

I would recommend two possible steps, either:

- Move away from inline styles (as they can be insecure) and will require you to change your CSP each time that the inline styles change.
- Add the supplied SHA to the StyleSources for your CSP. But Be aware that this will have to be maintained and updated for each inline style added across all pages in your application.

**UPDATE based on comments below answer**

> Note: There is no issue when i am running it in IE browser, only in the chrome and firefox i am getting the issue

Taking a look at [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=content%20security%20policy) shows that IE has only partial support for Content Security Policy, which would explain why you aren't seeing this error in the console. i.e. Internet Explorer doesn't support CSP, so it isn't applying it.

> I have fixed the issue by changing the hash keys shown in the browsers console error, I have replaced the console error hash key with my code hash key, but not sure whether this is the permanent solution or not

This is not really a permanent solution. If (and when) your inline styles change, you will have to change the hash in your CSP in order for the styles to be applied again.

Which leads me on to:

> Could you please guide me how the hash keys are getting generated and how i can fix this permanently

Looking at the code in your original question:

```cs
const string modernizrHash1 = "sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=";
const string modernizrHash2 = "sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs=";
// other things
.StyleSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/", modernizrHash1, modernizrHash2))
```

You are telling the browser (via the Content Security Policy that you are generating) that it is only permitted to load styles from:

- self (the origin domain of your site)
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/

and those which match the following hashes:

- sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
- sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs=

You mention that you've also included the hash:

- sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ=

When the browser starts to render the page, it will look at the resources that the page requires in order to render and will compare it to the list in the Content Security Policy. If a resource (inline styles and inline javascript are classed as a resource) is not in the list, then the browser will do a simple [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) of the contents of the resource and compares it to any of the hashes listed in the CSP.

Note: the same thing can be achieved by the use of a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

If the resource isn't from an allowed source, or it's hash does not match those listed in the CSP, then the browser will actively refuse it.

Because the SHA-2 algorithm uses the content of the resource to generate the hash, when the contents of it changes the calculated value of the hash will be different.

For example, the inline style here:

```html
<p style="color: red;">hello, world</p>
```

might hash to F1FF77E5DDBB1AF52EB51C98F725927143221549385937595112128987CF39E4 (which is the hash of "color:red")

whereas the following inline style:

```html
<p style="color: green;">hello, world</p>
```

might has to 2F262B22412B633D12B27FA9F94A3B0495821CB8341CFF0A88C80E3FED5DC9E8 (which is the hash of "color:green")

As you can see, there is a massive difference in the hashed styles. This is by design (in the algorithm).

To stop alleviate this problem, I would swap the inline styles for a css file describing how the content of the page should be styled. As long as the css file is served from the same origin as your HTML, then the `self` rule will cover it.

CSP is a pretty complex topic to pick up (but easy to master, once you have learned the basics). I would recommend taking a look at the [MDN page for Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for more information on how it works and how you can use it to secure your web applications.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by changing the hash keys shown in the browsers console error, I have replaced the console error hash key with my code hash key, but not sure whether this is the permanent solution or not.

Note: There is no issue when i am running it in IE browser, only in the chrome and firefox i am getting the issue.

Could you please guide me how the hash keys are getting generated and how i can fix this permanently

Comment: @NityanandaDas I have updated my answer to include a lot more information on this.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by changing the hash keys shown in the browsers console error, I have replaced the console error hash key with my code hash key, but not sure whether this is the permanent solution or not.

Note: There is no issue when i am running it in IE browser, only in the chrome and firefox i am getting the issue.

Could you please guide me how the hash keys are getting generated and how i can fix this permanently