# Angular 7 to 8 Upgrade: Cannot GET /home, build has no errors

Tags: node.js, angular, kendo-ui, mdbootstrap

I have an Angular 8 project that uses Kendo-UI and MDBootstrap.  `ng serve` shows no errors, but I get errors when I access `localhost:4200/home` in Chrome:

Webpage shows this text: `Cannot GET /home`

[image]

**Console**

```
15:25:29.258 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-mc5MFFuny++HbPmYE2clhmGeDbhhMCQG815PTPVKnzs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

(anonymous) @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
15:25:29.269 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-mc5MFFuny++HbPmYE2clhmGeDbhhMCQG815PTPVKnzs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

loadedCallback @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
15:25:29.271 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-mc5MFFuny++HbPmYE2clhmGeDbhhMCQG815PTPVKnzs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

loadedCallback @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
15:25:29.273 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1 Refused to load the script 'http://jonysource.com/optout/get?jsonp=__mtz_cb_213946739&key=213db237bbd6bf854a&t=1562703929272' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

script @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
15:25:29.275 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-mc5MFFuny++HbPmYE2clhmGeDbhhMCQG815PTPVKnzs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

loadedCallback @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
15:26:18.465 Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

15:26:18.465 Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

15:26:18.465 Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

15:26:18.465 Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

15:26:18.465 Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

15:26:18.082 home:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "eds4",
  "version": "1.0.14",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/EleMech/eds4.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "kendo-ui",
    "EDS4",
    "EleMech",
    "Business",
    "Software"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.800.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^3.12.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "1 - 2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.14.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "2 - 5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^3.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-ripple": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "^0.13.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-recurrence": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-material": "^2.5.1",
    "@progress/telerik-angular-report-viewer": "^7.19.514",
    "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.53",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.133",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.29",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "@types/ws": "^6.0.1",
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.5.3",
    "angular-websocket": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-websocket": "^0.9.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "git-update": "^1.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "inactivity-timer": "^1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-ws": "^4.0.1",
    "jest-serializer": "^24.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.18",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-business-days": "^1.1.3",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.1",
    "moment-precise-range-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "git+https://oauth2:XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXp@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git",
    "ngx-logger": "^3.3.13",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.1.4",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "npm-install-missing": "^0.1.4",
    "passport-ldapauth": "^2.1.3",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "pusher-angular": "^1.0.0",
    "queueing-subject": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-websockets": "^7.0.0",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "ws": "^7.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "terser": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "uglify-es": "npm:terser"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,    
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": ["node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["node_modules/core-js/es/*"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**ng --version**

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.0
Node: 12.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.801.0
@angular-devkit/core         8.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.1.0
@schematics/angular          8.1.0
@schematics/update           0.801.0
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Because I get no build errors I am not sure what the issue is and how to fix it.  The project worked previously with Angular 7.

Comment: Do you have a lot of inline styling? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766817/refused-to-apply-inline-style-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security

Comment: @NathanBeck I do not have a lot, but I will remove it and try to serve again.

Comment: I will likely need to restart from a new project, like I had to do with Angular 7 (i.e. `ng new eds4`)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. someone please suggest the solution.  No build errors. when reload the page i see cannot get / <pagename> its hosted in ec2 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my problem was that in `angular.json` I had these options set:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "eds4": {
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "options": {
                        "deployUrl": "/eds4/",
                        "baseHref": "/eds4/",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to go to http://localhost:4200/eds4/login not http://localhost:4200/login.

Comment: was that an acceptable solution to your problem or did you find out how to revert this?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros this was an acceptable solution for me since I host my website with IIS in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\eds4`, accessing it over port 80: `http://10.1.1.7/eds4/login`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is a helpful resource https://update.angular.io/
Follow each step hopefully that resolves your issue. This is step by step guide from angular to upgrade from 7 to 8

Comment: I have already followed this guide and made the necessary changes to my code (it builds without errors), but I have errors when I access the webpage.  Thank you.

Comment: Generally, answers that only refer to a link are discouraged. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.